# Adapt design to all devices with xcode in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm actually working on an IOS application, and i would like to see a background UIImageView in ScrollView.
My problem is that, i'm using Images.xcassets with this two pictures.

[image]

And there is my controller with those constraints.

[image]

On iphone6 and Iphone6+ i got this display which is correct

[image]

on Iphone5 i got that display with an horizontal scrollView

[image] [image]

Can i adapt the background image to the device screen, without the horizontally scroll on iphone5 ?

I'm actually using Xcode 7.0.1 with swift.

**UPDATED:**

Screen with the same width between my imageview, scrollview and rootview.

[image]

The other screen with the programming way using swift.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, you've added the image as actual content of the scrollview.
Which is fine, if it's supposed to scroll with the scrollview. If you didn't want it to scroll at all you could put it behind the ScrollView.

You can disable horizontal scrolling, better yet, add constraints to the image view, such that it has its width = to the superview of the scrollview, i.e. the view controller's root view.

Once this is done, you may also wish to add "centre" as the content mode for the image view, or whatever you wish, as there will be extra content and scaling will look worse. If your view isn't wide enough for all form factors you may be force to use aspect fill.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't understand well the part of "Add center as the content mode for the image view". I tried to add one constraint that gonna had the same width between my Image View and my Scroll View and the same width between my ScrollView and My root view, with View -> Mode set to "Scale to Fill". And the image appear well in the iphone5 without the scroll but the picture is deform. I updated my post with a screen of the result.

Comment: That's precisely my point. Please try content mode  "Scale Aspect Fill" it will scale the image as large as needed but keep all dimensions UNIFORMLY scales, i.e. in this case will scape it up large enough to fill all edges and crop the top and bottom most likely. Does that make sense? If that fails to be satisfactory, you could always centre the image view inside the scroll view and disable horizontal scrolling and make the image view large enough to hold the whole image while being centred

Comment: Thank you for your help, you help me to solve my problem. And i adjust it with constraints.

Comment: Glad to hear I helped. Please accept the answe if you feel it worked so others can know it's verified. :)